# JSON Format Error-Amzon EC2 instance creation

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i am doin Amazon Stack Creation through Java Eclipse.

tis below line of code is throwing the error

```
csr.setTemplateURL("https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-  1/AutoScalingMultiAZSample.template");
```

I am getting the error as :

Caught Exception: Parameters: [KeyName] must have values (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: 9363d711-3535-11e4-8cf2-913ef42879cb)
Reponse Status Code: 400

my json template url is
https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/AutoScalingMultiAZSample.template

Please help on this to detect the exact source of the error.

Comment: Why is there a string of blanks embedded in your URL? Is that a typo here or is it in the URL in your source?

Answer (score 1):

Ok i tried to validate your json schema using online validator.

http://jsonlint.com/

I just copied your json schema and pasted there. It said invalid schema expecting { on line 1. Ok for sure i have to put opening and closing brackets and in between your schema. But again it gave error. Extra Bracket } on last line. So i had to remove it. And then json schema was validated. It means somewhere in your schema you are putting an extra closing bracket }.

I think the place where you are making mistake is:

```
"InstanceSecurityGroup" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties" : {
        "GroupDescription" : "Enable SSH access and HTTP from the load balancer only",
        "SecurityGroupIngress" : [ {
          "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
          "FromPort" : "22",
          "ToPort" : "22",
          "CidrIp" : { "Ref" : "SSHLocation"}
        },
        {
          "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
          "FromPort" : { "Ref" : "WebServerPort" },
          "ToPort" : { "Ref" : "WebServerPort" },
          "SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId" : {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["ElasticLoadBalancer", "SourceSecurityGroup.OwnerAlias"]},
          "SourceSecurityGroupName" : {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["ElasticLoadBalancer", "SourceSecurityGroup.GroupName"]}
        } ]
      }
    }//Extra Bracket i think so
  },

  "Outputs" : {
    "URL" : {
      "Description" : "The URL of the website",
      "Value" :  { "Fn::Join" : [ "", [ "http://", { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "ElasticLoadBalancer", "DNSName" ]}]]}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: even after removing the bracket i am getting the same error in eclipse.i validated the schema in http://jsonlint.com/, there it is showin valid without removing the brackets.but if remove brackets then it is showin as parse error.please help.